# How To Build Application With Precompiled Library in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I am working with a precompiled library (.lib) that I wrote in Visual Studio 2010.  My solution has two projects.  The first project (C) builds the library.  The second project (C++) is a Win32 console application that is intended to test the library.  Everything I've tried does not resolve the linker errors.  (I thought this would be easy because everything is in the same solution.)  Any pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the linker error that I am getting:

> 1>MyProject.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl my_function(void)" (?my_function@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _wmain
>
> 1>C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\MySolution\Debug\MyProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

This is the code for the Win32 console application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "my_api.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  my_function();

  return 0;
}
```

Here's how `my_function` is declared in `my_api.h`:

```
extern VOID my_function(VOID);
```

Comment: Is the output directory of the .c library in the library path of the C++ project?  Unfortunately, just having them in the same solution isn't enough (as opposed to C#, where it's dead easy)

Comment: Don't make us guess at the linker errors.

Comment: @HansPassant: I do apologize.  Thank you for your courteous suggestion.  I've added the linker error and the code that causes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [declare your function with C linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B#Linking_C_and_C.2B.2B_code) in order for the linker to understand that those functions were defined in C code, not C++ code:

```
// my_api.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern VOID my_function(VOID);
// more function declarations etc.

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you only have one function, you can drop the braces:

```
// my_api.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
extern VOID my_function(VOID);
```

Comment: They're both good answers, but I'm accepting your because your feedback resolved a problem I hadn't even considered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the output directory of the library project (whatever `$(OutDir)` expands to in that project) is on the linker search path for the test project. To do this, go to the project Properties dialog. Under `Linker -> General`, make sure the directory is set in `Additional Library Directories`. Further, make sure under `Linker -> Input` that the library itself (`my_api.lib`) is listed in `Additional Dependencies`.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback!  You helped to cleanup my project settings. :)